# Get the rows those have got changes in a column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sales assignment table that stores the raw data as below.

```
SaleID     AssignedTo     ModDate
---------------------------------
1          aaaa           1-Aug
2          bbbb           1-AUg
3          cccc           1-Aug
1          eeee           5-Aug
3          ffff           6-Aug
```

The AssignedTo column in this table might keep changing. 
I need store the latest record when the AssignedTo changes for each SaleID in another table. Can somebody please help me on how can i identify those records that got changes to AssignedTo fields and store them in other table?

Thanks,
Venu

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Maybe use a trigger perhaps?

Comment: Are you inserting the data from a Stored Procedure, SSIS? If not @MarkKram is correct the only other way(if you dont have enterprise edition) is use a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest record for each sale by using `row_number()`. To insert the result into another table, oyu can use an `INSERT ... SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO table2
            (saleid,
             assignedto,
             moddate)
SELECT saleid,
       assignedto,
       moddate
       FROM (SELECT saleid,
                    assignedto,
                    moddate,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY saleid
                                       ORDER BY moddate DESC) row#
                    FROM table1) x
       WHERE row# = 1;
```

If the target table doesn't exist yet, you can also create and fill it in one go using `SELECT ... INTO`.

```
SELECT saleid,
       assignedto,
       moddate
       INTO table2
       FROM (SELECT saleid,
                    assignedto,
                    moddate,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY saleid
                                       ORDER BY moddate DESC) row#
                    FROM table1) x
       WHERE row# = 1;
```

Or, if you need an object, that can be queried like a table and always only shows the latest assignment and get "updated" automatically, you can use a view as [scsimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167855/scsimon) suggested in the comments to this answer.

```
CREATE VIEW view1
AS
SELECT saleid,
       assignedto,
       moddate
       FROM (SELECT saleid,
                    assignedto,
                    moddate,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY saleid
                                       ORDER BY moddate DESC) row#
                    FROM table1)
       WHERE row# = 1;
```

Comment: Good answer. I think this would be ideal in a view since the OP stated *I need store the latest record when the AssignedTo changes for each SaleID in another table*. They stated table, but contradicted that by saying *changes* so they could probably benefit from a view :)

Comment: @scsimon: A good idea too! I edited the answer to include the view option too.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the WITH TIES clause.

The following will return the current AssignedTo

**Example if the target table does NOT exist**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 Into  AnotherTable
 From  YourTable
 Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By SaleID Order by ModDate desc)
```

**Or if the target table does exist**

```
Insert Into Another Table
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By SaleID Order by ModDate desc)
```